# I have issue with print formatting in IE9

Tags: javascript, html, css, printing

I am using `window.print()` for printing document in my project. it is working fine except IE9. when i am using orientation : Landscape and Paper size A4 at that time image and description is not printing in proper format.

this issue is only with IE9 not with other IE versions.

Answer (score 0):

When printing HTML document, there are various aspects to consider in CSS to format your printing.

**THE [@PAGE](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2015/01/designing-for-print-with-css/) RULE**

The @page CSS at-rule is used to modify some CSS properties when printing a document. You can't change all CSS properties with @page. You can only change the margins, orphans, widows, and page breaks of the document. Attempts to change any other CSS properties will be ignored.

The @page rule lets you specify various aspects of a page box. For example, you will want to specify the dimensions of your pages. The rule below specifies a default page size of 5.5 by 8.5 inches. If you intend to print a book, perhaps by a print-on-demand service, then finding out the sizes you can use is important. In addition to specifying sizes with length values, you may also use paper size keywords, such as “A4″ or “legal.”

```
@page {
  size: A4;
}
```

Besides, you can always benefit from **The [@media](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/11/how-to-set-up-a-print-style-sheet/) Rule** to set custom CSS for your print page only.

```
@media screen {
    p {
        font-family: verdana, sans-serif;
        font-size: 17px;
    }
}

@media print {
    p {
        font-family: georgia, serif;
        font-size: 14px;
        color: blue;
    }
}
```

You can also use a separate style sheet for print as an alternative :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="print" href="print.css">
```

Since you are using IE, you might be facing some compatibility issues that are IE specific because of the way the rendering engine in IE deals with HTML and CSS, this is also something to consider to make your document print properly.